# Why do my blocks get stuck and refuse to fall to the lowest level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my grid-based blocks game I had trouble with the falling code for the game's blocks.

Here's the code snippet:

```
for (int i = (int)transform.position.y; i >= 0; i--)
         {
             if (transform.position.y >= 0 && SpawnBlocks.allBlocks[(int)gameObject.transform.position.x, i] == null)
             {
                 float timeElapsed = 0;
                 int initPos = (int)transform.position.y;
                 int targetPos = (int)transform.position.y - i;
                 timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime * 4;
                 float moveDown = Mathf.Lerp(initPos, targetPos, timeElapsed);
                 transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, moveDown);
 
                 SpawnBlocks.allBlocks[(int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.y] = gameObject;
                 gameObject.name = "(" + transform.position.x.ToString() + "," + transform.position.y.ToString() + ")";
             }
         }
```

Each block checks through a list to see whether there is a block beneath it. If there isn't, then it should smoothly lerp down that many blocks to fill it in.

There are three problems occurring however:

1. Blocks do not fall down to the lowest row
2. Even after one block has fallen down, blocks above that block in the same column won't go down and will be stuck up there.
3. If there is only a single space between blocks, then the block above will only move .016694 rather than a full 1
4. Instead of actually Lerping, blocks would just appear at the space beneath.

I do not know why the blocks act like this.

Here's an example pic of what is happening:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f77q6.png)

And here's an edited version showing what should happen:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYyOn.png)

Answer (score 0):

`SpawnBlocks.allBlocks[(int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.y] = gameObject;` can make this false `SpawnBlocks.allBlocks[(int)gameObject.transform.position.x, i] == null`, then `transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, moveDown);` will not be executed, so block can only drop a little bit before stopping.

Also I suggest not to use `float` for indexing. Try using `int` for logic, and trigger sort of coroutines for dropping animations.

Comment: So, how could I change SpawnBlocks.allBlocks[(int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.y] = gameObject; to stop the block from dropping a little? Removing it entirely causes the blocks to fall into each other.